# Javascript not working, classic asp, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, alert

Im trying to produce some validation alert boxes when something is done on my web page and for some reason my Javascript has stopped working after i put all the database calls into a separate include file (the javascript was working before i did this) ive tried everything i can think of and nothing has worked so far so ive come to the final frontier to ask for help, here is my html form that starts the database call:

```
<form name="requestHol" action="newbooking.asp" method="post">              

    <div id="datepicker">
        <label for="from">From </label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" readonly="readonly" >
        <label for="to">to </label>
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" readonly="readonly" >
    </div>

    <div id="reason">
        <textarea id="reasonInput" name="RequestComments" placeholder="Please enter the reason for your absence." maxlength="45" ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="reqbutton">
        <button name="submitHolBtn" value="requestButton" type="submit">Submit Request</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

here is my ASP database call:

```
If(Request.Form("submitHolBtn"))<>""Then

        If(Request.Form("from"))="" or (Request.Form("to"))="" or (Request.Form("RequestComments"))="" Then
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Please make sure you fill in ALL inputs when booking a holiday.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        else

        Set objDBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        objDBConn.Open Application("ConnString")

        Set objDBCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

        objDBCommand.ActiveConnection = objDBConn
        objDBCommand.CommandText = "spNewHoliday"
        objDBCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

        objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput,200)
        objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput,200)
        objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@EmployeeID", adVarChar, adParamInput,200)          
        objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@Reason", adVarChar, adParamInput,200)
        objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@JobRoleID", adVarChar, adParamInput,200)  

        objDBCommand("@StartDate") = Request.Form("from")
        objDBCommand("@EndDate") = Request.Form("to")
        objDBCommand("@EmployeeID") = Session("UserID")
        objDBCommand("@Reason") = Request.Form("RequestComments")
        objDBCommand("@JobRoleID") = Session("JobRoleID")

        Set objDBRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

        objDBRS.open objDBCommand,,adOpenForwardOnly

        Session("IsBookingValid") = objDBRS(0)

        SELECT CASE Session("IsBookingValid")
        Case "HolidayBooked"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Holiday has been requested.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "TooManyPeopleOfFSameJob"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Holiday CANNOT be booked, Max amount of employees with the same job role are off.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "TooManyPeopleOff"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Holiday CANNOT be booked, Max amount of employees are already off.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "YouHaveAlreadyBookedThisDateOff"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You have already booked these dates off.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "YouCanOnlyBookAMaxOf10Days"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You can only book a max of 10 days off at a time.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "YouDontHaveEnoughHolidaysLeft"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You do not have enough days left to book that holiday off.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        Case "YouHaveAlreadyBookedAHolidayInThatPeriod"
            response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You already have a holiday booked off during that time period.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
        END SELECT

        Set objDBCommand=nothing
        objDBConn.Close
        Set objDBConn=nothing

        end if 
    end if
```

any and all help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your question is about JavaScript, so please show the resulting HTML not the asp.

Comment: The resulting HTML is the normal page with no javascript alert @phylax

Comment: I dont know asp but your qouting look ominous. `"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">`. Should it be like: `'<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">'`?

Comment: No, that would comment out the code @phylax

Comment: So when your asp does not generate the ouput you want there is a problem with asp not with javascript. Maybe remove the javascript tag? As i said i dont know anything about asp, sorry.

Comment: What does newbooking.asp contain? What exactly do you mean by "put all the database calls into a separate include file"? Because the code you posted is way more than just database calls - it's where you seem to be doing all of your validation. Why are you using Javascript to do server-side validation?

Comment: @phylax - in classic ASP you can use double double quotes to escape quotes in a response write statement.  eg `response.write "<div class=""myclass"">"` would output `<div class="myclass">`

Comment: @Martha I'm not using JS to do server side validation (or i dont think i am, this is my first major web application project haha), the case statements are just letting the user know what has happened to their requests, as for the first if statement with javascript that stops the data being pushed if anything is wrong with the inputted data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to validate your form client side with Javascript or server side with classic asp.  If you want to do it client side then your asp code is irrelevant and you need attach some javascript to your form.

If you want to validate server side then your best bet is to have your insert code and your form on the same page, with the asp coming before the form - eg

```
<%
If(Request.Form("submitHolBtn"))<>""Then

    If(Request.Form("from"))="" or (Request.Form("to"))="" or (Request.Form("RequestComments"))="" Then
        response.Write "<p class=""alerttext"">Please make sure you fill in ALL inputs when booking a holiday.</p>"
    else

    'your db code and cases

    end if
end if
%>

<form name="requestHol" method = "post">
<div id="datepicker">
    <label for="from">From </label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="<%=Request.Form("from")%>" readonly="readonly" >
    <label for="to">to </label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="<%=Request.Form("to")%>" readonly="readonly" >
</div>

<div id="reason">
    <textarea id="reasonInput" name="RequestComments" placeholder="Please enter the reason for your absence." maxlength="45" ><%=Request.Form("RequestComments")%>"</textarea>
</div>

<div id="reqbutton">
    <button name="submitHolBtn" value="requestButton" type="submit">Submit Request</button>
</div>
<form>
```

I wouldn't use js at all for the alerts, just text.  As the code is processed server side it will only appear on the page if relevant, and you can have multiple error messages displayed at once rather than a string of js alerts

Comment: Really i want to be validating it both client side and server side, for added extra validation :), and how do you mean 'just text'? like HTML text or JavaScript?

Comment: @Jimmy_Chong: bravo, that is the way to do it. However, you shouldn't mix the two - for the server-side validation, write out your messages in HTML, and for the client-side, do all of your error checking in a function attached to the form ("onsubmit"), and if you find errors, pop up a *single* messagebox with *all* of the errors noted. Otherwise, you're teasing the user: "Fix this and I'll accept it. Oops, I lied, fix this too, *then* I'll take it. Nope, lied again, you have to fix that too."

Comment: @Jimmy_Chong Martha explains it pretty well - by text I mean html text, ideally above the form or adjacent to the relevant field, you shouldn't be "response writing" javascript.  As far as client side validation goes, take a look at jQuery validation methods.  Javascript popup alerts are a bit last decade.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
 If(Request.Form("from"))="" or (Request.Form("to"))="" or (Request.Form("RequestComments"))="" Then
        response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""Please make sure you fill in ALL inputs when booking a holiday.""); location.href = 'newbooking.asp'</SCRIPT>")
    else
```

If any of your request.form empty - page will be reloaded so fast that you would not even be able to see anything - it is old page all over again. Do response.write for each Request.Form with response.end to see what are you submitting to the page.
Also look what value Session("IsBookingValid") have, if any...
In your place I would put before end of case following:

```
case else
       response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('You have nothing for ASP  to work with.');</SCRIPT>")
    END SELECT
```

location.href = 'newbooking.asp' is a good when you redirecting somewhere else but since you posting to the same page you do not need it, more over it will mess you up. Just make sure that your response.write writing javascript in body and not in header.

When you moved asp code into include file could it be that by accident you removed JS file for calendar? If so then all your datepickers fields TO and FROM will be empty...